# Save image as base64 in NSUSERDEFAULTS as NSDICTIONARY

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am actually using the following code to save data entered in text field and image selected in image view in NSUSERDEFAULTS as dictionary.Thecode is working well for saving textfield.text but it can't save image as base64 in dictionary.Kindly review the code and suggest the corrections.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    _profileImageView.image = image;

    UIImage *updatedImage =  _profileImageView.image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(updatedImage, 100);

    NSString *strEncoded = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];


    [_userDetailsDictionary setObject:strEncoded forKey:@"UpdatedImage"];


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}


- (IBAction)saveAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {


    NSLog(@"the values stored in dictionary are %@",_userDetailsDictionary);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_userDetailsDictionary forKey:@"UpdatedDetails"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    ConnectionManager * connectionManager = [ConnectionManager sharedConnectionManager];
    connectionManager.delegate = self;
    [connectionManager sendUserUpdatedDetailsToServer:_userDetailsDictionary withToken:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"token"]];



}
```

Comment: You need to say what error you are getting and where, what you have tried to resolve it, what the debugger told you about the values of your variables, etc., etc. Edit your question and provide these details and someone might be able to help you.

Comment: you don't want saving binary blob into `NSUserDefaults`, you have e.g. the  _Documents/_ folder, and you are supposed to use that for permanent storing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to save image as string in NSUserdefaults it is weird decision. You can just save it as NSData. Or a better approach is to save it in app sandbox Doc folder.

Also I notice this code is wrong:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(updatedImage, 100);
```

compression quality is CGFloat from 0.0-1.0. 100 is out of range.

Comment: I actually want to save the details obtained from user together as dictionary and then post it on server

Comment: You CAN save as NSData in dictionary. NSData is an accepted property list type. So, there is no need to convert the image as string.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample project using your code and its working fine for me.
Please download it from below link and try to run

http://wikisend.com/download/464846/aaa.zip